# Tabbed content for WordPress sidebar

Tags: jquery

Is there a tutorial that will show me how to create a custom tabbed content area for my sidebar? I want to have two tabs - one for a specific category each (news & events) This tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-tabbed-interface-using-jquery/ shows how to create the tabs but how do I add the code for WordPress to show the excerpts of posts with thumbnail images from the categories so it shows in the selected tab?

Answer (score 1):

Follow that tutorial and use below code for specific category recent post where tutorial used un order list content.

```
<ul>
    <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=1&showposts=10"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Change cat id and number of post as per your choice.

Comment: Thanks pixelgrain. Will that show a thumbnail as well or do I have to do something else?

Comment: to show post thumbnail you need to add post thumbnail snippet where you want to show.

something like `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` and if you want to link that thumbnail to the post than use permalink like `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>`